# Converting huge amount of small PDF files to PNG

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, pdf, imagemagick

I need to transform over 500k pdf files to png (with the sufficient density) tpo be able to treat it later (reading a QR code embedded in the pdf). The files normally don't surpass 200kb

I tried using magick to convert it (first using convert and then mogrify), but figured that it will take days to finish and figured that maybe doing it with threads was better. So i implemented a little app in java that creates n threads and executes in the windows shell (Runtime.getRuntime().exec()) a builded command with the file and target and all that.

Problem is it kills my pc. Apparently magick uses multithreads for processing each images and since some of those are taken by the script I did, it takes longer and takes resources that the jvm wouldnt normally take. Here is my code:

```
public class SuperPdfToPngConverter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Setting Up Environment...");

    System.out.println("Reading existing files...");

    // To change according to our needs
    String targetFolder = "D:\\Digest";

    // Execution parameters


    ArrayList<String> myList = getTodoList(targetFolder);
    ArrayList<String> rejected = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("I've found " + myList.size() + " documents pending to be converted.");

    System.out.println(" Treating files... ");
    int count = 1;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);

    for (String fileId : myList) {

        System.out.println("Queueing file " + count + ", " + fileId);

        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(fileId, targetFolder, true, 150);
        executor.execute(worker);

        //rejected.add(fileId);
        count++;
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }

    System.out.println("Finished");
    System.out.println(
            "Treated " + (count - 1) + " documents; ");

}
```

And the working part on each thread goes like this:

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start. File = "+ fileName);
    processCommand();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");
}

private void processCommand() {

    String fileNamePng = fileName.replace(".pdf", ".png");


    String cmd = "magick convert -density " + density + "x" + density + " " + fileName + " " + fileNamePng;
    System.out.println(cmd);


    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, new File(targetPath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Document " +  fileName + " processed.");        
}
```

I was wondering what can I do to make this run a little bit faster and stable. I don't care much about how long it takes (as long as its reasonable).

Do you think my approach is good? Is it better if I use a library rather than a tool like magick?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: maybe you have to play around till you find the optimum number of threads, i.e. where it runs fastest overall

Comment: Do you have access to a proper computer where you can run Linux and use powerful tools like **GNU Parallel**? If so, I would suggest you use that along with `mogrify` rather than `convert` so that you can do multiple PDF files with a single process rather than starting a whole new process for each of 500,000 files.

Comment: IM uses GhostScript to convert PDFs so maybe you could just run it directly like this `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile=output-%d.png input.pdf'